# Django ListView

Tags: python, django

It's my first time to use ListView and it doesn't work and give me error.
I put get_query but they still give me same error. How can I fix the problem?
And everytime when I write code in views.py I always used 'def' not 'class'. But could see many people use (and also django documents) 'class' for ListView. So for general render stuffs we use 'def' and for django.views.generic stuffs we use class right? Why they distinguished these two?
This is error what I got.

```
ImproperlyConfigured at /search/results
ListView is missing a QuerySet. Define ListView.model, ListView.queryset, or override ListView.get_queryset().
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView

from . import views


app_name = 'search'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name = "search/index.html")),
    path('results', ListView.as_view(template_name = 'search/results.html')),
    path('beerlist', views.beerlist, name='beerlist'),
    path('<int:beerinfo_id>', views.beerinfo, name='beerinfo'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.db.models import Q
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView

from .models import Beerinfo

# Create your views here.
def index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'search/index.html'

def results(ListView):
    model = Beerinfo
    template_name = 'search/results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Beerinfo.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains = query) | Q(label__icontains = query)
        )
        return obejct_list
```

index.html

```
<form action="{% url 'search:results' %}" name="se">
    <label for='search'>What do you want to find?</label>
    <input type="text" name='q'>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

results.html

```
<ul>
    {% for beer in ojbect_list %}
        <li><a href="/search/{{ beer.id }}">{{ beer.name }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Beerinfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the class that the list view will work with. For example:

```
class UserListView(ListView):
    model = User
```

You can use a function (def) to accomplish the same thing that a generic view class, the difference is that most of what you write in the function is already defined in the class. In my example above, that class already handles the rendering of a default template, a context with the list of object of that template and pagination. The idea is to keep your code [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

The second advantage is that it creates a standard for your code, for example the default template to be used is 
`%(app_label)s/%(model_name)s%(template_name_suffix)s.html`, so if your app name is `users` and your model is `User`, the this view expects a template named `users/userlist.html`

To use the pagiation simply set the `paginate_by` attribute of the class.

If you are trying to implement a simple view (for example all [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) actions, then is very likely that you will benefit from using clases. Another good thing that classes give you, is that you can inherit goodies, for example, you can create a `BaseListView` class that inherits from `ListView` and set `paginate_by` to 25. If all your clases inherit from `BaseListView` then all your list will be paginated by 25 elements.

Comment: Thank you for really nice answer. I understand why I have to use class for it.
But still I get that error of 'ImproperlyConfigured at /search/results'.
I guess it's different problem with 'class' or 'def'

Answer (score 1):

In views.py change def to class , you need to define a class to use Listview, Class Results(ListView). In urls.py, you are calling Listview , you should call views.Results.as_view()

Comment: Yes! It was the problem of url :( Thank you so much!